# About the T-S diagram

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose we have a T-S diagram of some vapor thermodynamic cycle , say the rankine cycle , and we are interested for example in the composition of the liquid and the vapor in the middle of the condensation process ;  knowing only the entropy of both the liquid and vapor at that point (or the enthalpy) , how exactly do we get the composition at that point ?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! This question sounds like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29/lets-decide-on-a-homework-policy) question; What are your attempts at the problem? Where exactly lies your problem in understanding these questions?

Comment: @tschoppi , definetly not a homework , i was googling the "lever rule" , but unfortunately i didn't find anything .